# How to Activate Amasty's Color Swatch Pro (paid extension) on Magento via Localhost?

Tags: magento

The site we are working on locally is a copy of a site that is currently live. That site uses Amasty's paid extension called Color Swatch Pro.

Is there a way to get that extension to work locally? We are updating the theme of the site and need to see how the extension will be implemented then make any changes necessary.

Our local root folder already has all the same Amasty related folders/files yet the extension doesn't appear in the admin panel.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Unless the extension has a activation key request built in, there is no good reason why extensions shouldn't work locally

Comment: Also on a side note, you might get a better response on the Magento StackExchange than here

Comment: Yes, we've cleared the cache, reindexed, logged out/in — all to no avail. 

Considering it is a paid extension, it most likely does have to do with an activation key. We've contacted the previous the developer in regards to the purchase of the extension — hoping to get a key we can input to Magento Connect.

And thanks, new user to stackoverflow — wasn't aware there were separate subforums.

Comment: How did you install the extension? Is it committed into a code repository or installed via Connect?

Comment: We just manually copied all the relevant files we could find. `app/code/community/amasty`
`js/amasty`
and the two XML files in:
`app/etc/modules`

Comment: What about app/etc/modules/Amasty_ColorSwatchPro.xml (or similar name)?

Comment: We haven't seen that particular XML at all. Just Amasty_Base.xml and Amasty_Conf.xml. I ran a search the ColorSwatchPro file on the live FTP and it didn't come up.

Comment: Ok, make sure you copy all the Amasty XML files. The base one would be important as it provides common functionality for all their modules

Comment: The Base and Conf files I mentioned have already been copied over. But from a search of the public_html folder of "amasty xml", I do see: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/amasty/ambase.xml`
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/amconf.xml`
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/ampgrid.xml` 
And several others that mention amasty. Should I be comparing all of those to our local directory?

Comment: You should install the package from scratch if you've paid for it. Get Amasty support involved. Otherwise copy everything from your production instance to local- you should have a realistic development environment anyway

Comment: From scratch would be ideal. As mentioned, we're waiting to hear back from the previous developer that handled the extension. 

We do have a local copy of the entire production directory but it has two different themes that conflict with the new theme we're working with in development. In the meantime, I suppose we can target the theme's files/folders and delete that.